# OnvalidSubmit fires and EditContext.Validate() returns true even though my model is intentionally invalid

Tags: c#, blazor

In my Blazor Server App project, I have an EditForm which includes my EditContext and OnValidSubmit method.

`<EditForm EditContext="@EditContext" OnValidSubmit="@UpdateProject">` 
I declare and initialize my EditContext as follows:

```
private EditContext EditContext;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        EditContext = new(supplementedProjectModel);
    }
```

and my model:

```
    SupplementedProjectModel supplementedProjectModel = new();
```

When I submit my model with my submit button

```
        <button type="submit" class="btn button-primary">Spara</button>
```

it fires the OnValidSubmit event EVEN THOUGH my model is intentionally invalid with empty inputs where my model contains

```
[Required]
```

attributes. Why?

Model:

```
public class SupplementedProjectModel
    {
        public CinodeDataModel CinodeDataModel = new();
    }
```

```
    public class CinodeDataModel
{
        public Webhook webhook { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Webhook
        {
            public WebhookModel WebhookModel { get; set; }
        }
```

```
public class WebhookModel
        {
            public Payload Payload { get; set; }
        }
```

```
public class Payload
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Uppdragsnamn obligatorisk")]
            public string Title { get; set; }
        }
```

My second issue is inside the OnValidSubmit method, the EditContext.Validate() ALWAYS return true. Why is that?

```
protected async Task UpdateProject()
    {
bool IsValid = EditContext.Validate();
        EditContext = new(supplementedProjectModel);
        bool isreallyvalid = EditContext.Validate();
        if (IsValid)
        {
// UPDATE MODEL
}
}
```

I have tried with all these annotation validators and CLEARLY see my errors when I run the project and input invalid data.

```
@*<ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />*@
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
```

Within my UpdateProject method, should my EditContext be populated with the current model values or not? I would assume so but could not find anything therefore I test the Validate method before and after initializing it again.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

> it fires the OnValidSubmit event EVEN THOUGH my model is intentionally invalid with empty inputs where my model contains....

You have a deep model so you have to use the `ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator` or build your own.  You need to make sure your `objects` in your model tree are annotated with `[ValidateComplexType]`.  See my 3 level model in the demo.  Note I have Nullable enabled - `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` set in my project file.

Demo Page:

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<EditForm EditContext=this.editContext OnValidSubmit=this.OnValidSubmit OnInvalidSubmit=this.OnInValidSubmit  >
    <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="p-2 mb-3">Normal edit fields here</div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <ValidationSummary />
</EditForm>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <div>Forename: @model.Person.Name.Forename</div>
    <div>Surame: @model.Person.Name.Surname</div>
    <div>Value: @model.Value</div>
</div>

@if (this.message != string.Empty)
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        @message
    </div>
}

@code {
    private MyModelData model = new();
    private EditContext? editContext;
    private string message = string.Empty;

    public Task OnValidSubmit()
    {
        this.message = "Valid Submit";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task OnInValidSubmit()
    {
        this.message = "InValid Submit";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.editContext = new EditContext(model);
    }

    public class MyModelData 
    {
        [ValidateComplexType]
        public Person Person { get; set; } = new();

        [Required]
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        [ValidateComplexType]
        public PersonName Name { get; set; } = new();
    }

    public class PersonName
    {
        [Required]
        public string? Forename { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? Surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've edited the post and added my model with my required property. As you can see, it is embedded deep in the model.

Comment: The missing bit!  See my revised answer.  Use `ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator` and make sure you annotate correctly with `[ValidateComplexType] `.